# Ruby on Rails on OSX - did I mess up my install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I just installed Rails on OSX. I used the stock version of Ruby and followed the following procedure:

1. Installed newest version of RubyGems
2. Ran sudo gem install rails --include-dependencies
3. Installed Mongrel using sudo gem install mongrel --include-dependencies

Rails is working just fine, but more reading led me to this setup guide:

http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-mongrel-mysql-osx

This is essentially the exact same install I performed, except he compiles it from source code and installs to /usr/local -- I really like this idea, since it keeps the OSX install stock and confines all my dev stuff to one area.

So, assuming I want to follow these instructions, what do I need to do to revert my system back to "stock" ruby? Can I just uninstall the Rails and Mongrel gems? Will the upgraded RubyGems cause any issues?

Basically, my concern is that some other software unrelated to my development work will need to use OSX's stock Ruby, and I will have screwed it up somehow. Any advice to undo the 3 steps I listed above and get as close to stock as possible would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article you are referring to is over three years old (which is outdated in the Rails community). My recommendation is:

1. Install XCode
2. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
3. Install MySQL, Postgres, Image Magick, etc. (brew install mysql, etc.)
4. Install [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)
5. Install Ruby 1.9.2 (rvm install 1.9.2)
6. Switch to default (rvm 1.9.2 --default)
7. Install Rails (gem install rails)
8. Install Passenger (gem install passenger)

Each step will have a few more substeps but you should be able to look them up or be promted with them.

Comment: couldn't have said it better myself

Comment: Thanks for the info - I have heard nothing but good things re: RVM - but what about undoing what I've already done? Any issues just uninstalling those gems and then installing a new version with RVM?

Comment: @Jim You  don't have to undo anything, but I typically delete all the default gems from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 using an `rm -rf`.

Comment: @Jim You can also go through your gems first using `sudo uninstall rails` for example. However, some gems will not uninstall using this.

Comment: @Kevin - thanks for the detailed instructions! I'll give it a shot tonight!

Comment: @Kevin - so removing the Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 contents will get rid of everything? Would there be any reason to do the gem uninstall instead of the rm command?

Comment: @Jim This command also gets rid of the gems that Mac OS X ships with (mostly old versions). Using gem uninstall will leave the system gems alone (I believe). Ultimately it shouldn't matter either way.

Comment: @Kevin - sorry, one other question - looking at my gem environment, I have 3 gem paths - the /System/Library/Frameworks/.../gems/1.8 (which I rm'd per your above instructions), one in my home dir (the folder doesn't even exist) and finally, /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 - this one seems to have all the new gems I installed - Rails 3.0.5, Mongrel 1.1.5, etc... should I delete those as well before installing RVM?

Comment: @Jim You could delete them. Although deleting all these shouldn't have any effect on RVM.

Comment: @Kevin - thanks, used Homebrew and RVM to get everything going last night - so far, working flawlessly!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember why I did this but I do know that it worked and has caused no problems since. I moved /Library/Ruby to /Library/Ruby.broken and then installed Ruby from source into /usr/local.

There's something fundamentally missing with the stock Ruby in OSX. I wish I could remember what that was.

Comment: You probably shouldn't kill the system Ruby as it's used by RubyCocoa applications and is also intermittently patched by OS updates. Whatever you do to hide it could be undone by a patch and lead to a confused system state. Installing from source is also a bad idea when there's tools like RVM, MacPorts and Homebrew that will compile and install Ruby properly.